# BIC() and regsubsets() give me different answers

Tags: r, linear-regression

i have this Dataframe :

```
# install.packages(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(
          sales = c(-48,-11,24,26,67,60,40,42,20,-9,17,-21),
          P1 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
          P10 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
          P11 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
          P12 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
          P2 = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
          P3 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
          P4 = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
          P5 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
          P6 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
          P7 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
          P8 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
          P9 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
          )
print(df)
```

it gives me this :

```
# A tibble: 13 x 13
    sales    P1   P10   P11   P12    P2    P3    P4    P5    P6    P7    P8
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 -48        1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2 -11        0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3  24        0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 4  26        0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
 5  67        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 6  60        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 7  40        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 8  42        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 9  20        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
10  -9        0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
11  17        0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
12 -21        0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# ... with 1 more variable: P9 <dbl>
```

with the package leaps i can compare differents models :

```
#install.packages("leaps")
library("leaps")
regsubsets.out<- regsubsets(sales ~ .,  df , nbest = 1, method = "exhaustive")
summary.out <- summary(regsubsets.out)  
#compare models of different size sorted by bic (in this example)
plot(regsubsets.out, scale = "bic", main = "BIC")
```

it gives me this result :
[image: bic graph]

As you can see in this picture, the best model with the minimum BIC is the model sales~P1+P10+P12+P2+P5+P6+P7+P8 with a BIC = -21

```
inspected_model <- lm(sales~P1+P10+P12+P2+P5+P6+P7+P8, data = df)
print(BIC(inspected_model))
# ---> 108.612
```

Why my results are totally different ? there's obviously something i missed with one of these functions but i don't know what...

PS: this is not a statistical question because it talks about its programmation

Comment: In `regsubsets` you use `data=temporaire`, in `lm` `data=df`. Is that maybe causing a difference?

Comment: sry it's an error i edited the code above

Comment: perhaps leaps does not include the normalising constant in the likelihood? - you will need to inspect the code to compare.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question can be found [HERE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87468/why-do-i-get-different-bic-values-when-i-use-regsubsets-and-lm-in-r). In summary, y-axis is likely the drop in BIC compared to the intercept-only model, not the model BIC. To get the model BIC for comparison use `BIC(model1,model2,...)`